# ExpressionSet (ESet) delete entry with NA

Tags: r, statistics, expression, bioconductor

I am try to exclude all my sample out of a ESet which have for a one of 10 phenotype no entry:

I have a ESet with 50 samples and 10 phenotypes. Sample A has NA in Phenotype 1 and Sampe B in Phenotype 3. So I want to delete A and B in my ESet.

> I try:
>   apply(ESest@pData@data,1,function(i){if(is.na(i)){???}}

Sorry But I have no idea ;(

Answer (score 3):

As said last time, please use the correct getter and setter methods to get to the data you want. In this case, it would be :

```
ESet[rowSums(is.na(pData(ESet)))==0,]
```

`pData()` gives you the dataframe with phenodata, and with the condition you check whether any of the rows in the pData dataframe contains an NA.